# Checking if Image Exists in Bundle - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk, nsfilemanager

I have an app with a number of images. I want to check if an image exists in the bundle. If it does I display it, if not I display a replacement image.

The code below is what I've come up with, however it does not work. Can anyone spot what is wrong ?

Thank you !

```
NSString * photo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", UniqueID];    

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:photo];
if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
{

    [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:photo]];  
}

else {

    NSLog(@"Hello");

    [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhoneHD.png"]];

}
```

EDIT - Changed following Simon's post below, however still not working correctly. Else statement always triggers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are looking in your App's Documents directory. Is this really where you are expecting to find the images? If they are actually resources added to your bundle then you need to do this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:uniqueID ofType:@"jpg"];
```

Easier still - just try loading the named image. If it fails then load the default:

```
UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:photo];

if (!tempImage) {
    tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhoneHD.jpg"]
}

[image setImage:tempImage];
```

Comment: Edited response to confirm whether you really want to look in the Documents directory or you actually want your App's bundle.

Answer (score 17):

```
+(BOOL) fileExistsInProject:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *fileInResourcesFolder = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    return [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fileInResourcesFolder];
}
```

is my answer.

---

returns YES if file is exist in bundle.you dont have to do anything with path.
just say [fileExistsInProject:@"blabla.ext"]

Answer (score 6):

You have the if statement the wrong way, you are saying if it DOESN'T exist, then use it, otherwise use the default one.....you want...

```
if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
```

Comment: Hi Simon. Thanks but it still doesn't work. The else statement is triggered everytime, even if the file exists.

Comment: It should definitely work. The thing is you can't just pass in file name as path. You need something like this: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"png"]